# E Reader SDK for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, epub

I am working on an application where i need to open E Reader within the mobile app. I am using Xamarin for mobile development and I will like to know whether there are E Reader SDKs available for Xamarin ?

E Reader needs to support pdf & ePub files atleast.

I am doing research for past few days and haven't found anything. Any help is much appreciated.

We are also willing to create custom E reader if anyone can point us to right direction.

Comment: There are dozens of ePub SDKs ranging from Adobe Reader Mobile SDK, smaller company's commercial SDKs to open source SDKS. Almost all are platform specific due to the graphic rendering requirements, but using binding projects you can abstract your app requirements away from the actual reader/renderer.... Google is your friend, I found 8 with one search...

Comment: @SushiHangover: Can you suggest some open source SDKs. Also will these SDKs open e reader within the app ?

Comment: The Radium Foundation has a cross-platform/mobile C++ based SDK for embedding EPUB3 into applications....